# Geodesic torsion of two perpendicularly intersecting curves

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I am working on an extension of 3.2 #19a from Do Carmo that asks what the relationship between the geodesic torsions is at the point of intersection between two curves, given that they intersect perpendicularly. I understand how to prove #19, but am having a hard time with the intuition behind the relationship between geodesic curvature for the different curves.

For reference, Do Carmo #19a proves the result that:

$\tau_g=(k_2-k_1)\cos\phi \sin\phi$

where $\phi$ is the angle from $e_1$ to $t$ and $\tau_g$ is the geodesic torsion.

Intuitively, I want to say that because for two curves $\alpha(t),\beta(t)$ that intersect perpendicularly at $t=0$, $\phi_\alpha=\phi_\beta\pm \pi/2$, and from that $\cos(\phi_\beta) = \mp\sin(\phi_\alpha)$ and $\sin(\phi_\beta) = \cos(\phi_\alpha)$, then $\tau_{g,\alpha} = \pm\tau_{g,\beta}$.

This feels too simple and I feel like I am missing part of the analysis, though I don't know where I am going wrong.

Can anyone offer me any guidance?

Comment: Please edit your post to include all these details, showing precisely what you’ve done. Also, do not assume we all know the problem in DoCarmo to which you refer.

Comment: Your analysis is perfect. (I don't know why this is "intuitive," but the math is correct.) It's worth noting, I guess, that if you go backwards along the curve, the geodesic torsion switches sign?

Comment: (Actually, that last remark of mine is wrong. Reversing direction on the curve should not change the sign. This is consistent with the formula you have with $\phi$.)